# Error “env: node: No such file or directory” with child_process.spawn in only .app (distribution file)

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I get an “env: node: No such file or directory” error when i try to run my node module in child process from main process of Electron app:

```
this._process = spawn(`path/to/node_modules/.bin/my_file`, args)
```

I tried with options = `{env: process.env}` for spawn but it still didn't work. Also, I tried to workaround with `asar = true/false`.

My environment:

> Mac OSX 10.11, electron v0.35.0